How can I remove the wrapper page when using publishHTML
I'm using publishHTML from the Jenkins HTML Publisher plugin to preview Sphinx documentation for each build.
publishHTML([
    reportDir: 'path/to/my/html',
    reportFiles: 'index.html',
    reportName: "Generated Documentation",
    keepAll: true
])

By default, this generates some wrapper HTML and puts the page into an iframe. I can directly access the inner page by viewing source and going to the iframe's source, but is there any way to point the sidebar link directly at the non-iframe page?

I think you are referring to the the wrapper that adds the "Back to #{Build Number}", And Download Zip links at the top of the report.
There is no current way of having the link work without an iframe as it needs it for the navigation functionality.
There is an option: useWrapperFileDirectly "By default, each archived reports access generates a new wrapper file. If checked, the legacy wrapper file will be used instead of generate it each time. Must only be used if wrapper file was been transformed and saved with checksum" but I don't believe this actually removes it, however, it's worth setting this to false and seeing what happens.
